# Converting a set of classes to class templates and avoiding constructor ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, c++17, disambiguation

I will try to make this question as short as I can but there is a good amount of code to show in order for one to understand what I'm trying to achieve and how to resolve my current issue.

Here are my original class declarations with all of their constructors:

**Register.h** - *Original Version*

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::uint8_t u8;
typedef std::uint16_t u16;
typedef std::uint32_t u32;
typedef std::uint64_t u64;

const u16 BYTE = 0x08, WORD = 0x10, DWORD = 0x20, QWORD = 0x40;

typedef std::bitset<BYTE> Byte;
typedef std::bitset<WORD> Word;
typedef std::bitset<DWORD> DWord;
typedef std::bitset<QWORD> QWord;

template<typename T>
void getByteFrom(T val, u8 idx, u8& res) {
    res = ((val >> (idx * 8) & 0xff));
}

template<typename T>
void getWordFrom(T val, u8 idx, u16& res) {
    res = ((val >> (idx * 16) & 0xffff));
}

template<typename T>
void getDWordFrom(T val, u8 idx, u32& res) {
    res = ((val >> (idx * 32) & 0xffffffff));
}

template<typename T>
struct Register {
    T data;
    Register() = default;
};

struct Reg8 : public Register<u8> {
    u8 value;  // must be declared before std::bitset<T>
    Byte bits;

    // Default 0 Initialized Constructor
    Reg8() : value{ 0 }, bits{ value } { this->data = 0; }

    // Constructors by Register Sized Values
    explicit Reg8(u8 val)  : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg8(u16 val) : value{ static_cast<u8>( val ) }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg8(u32 val) : value{ static_cast<u8>( val ) }, bits{ value } {
        //this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg8(u64 val) : value{ static_cast<u8>( val ) }, bits{ value } {
        //this->data = value;
    }

    Reg8(u16 val, u8 idx ) {
        assert( idx == 0 || idx == 1 );
        getByteFrom(val, idx, this->value);
        bits = value;
        this->data = value;
    }

    Reg8(u32 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx <= 0 && idx >= 3);
        getByteFrom(val, idx, this->value);
        bits = value;
        this->data = value;
    }

    Reg8(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx <= 0 && idx >= 7);
        getByteFrom(val, idx, this->value);
        bits = value;
        this->data = value;
    }

    // Constructors by Register Types
    template<typename T>
    explicit Reg8(Register<T>* reg) {
        this->value = static_cast<u8>( reg->data );
        this->bits = value;
    }
};

struct Reg16 : public Register<u16> {
    u16  value;  // must be declared before std::bitset<T>
    Word bits;

    // Default 0 Initialized Constructor
    Reg16() : value{ 0 }, bits{ value } { this->data = 0; }

    // Constructors by Register Sized Values
    explicit Reg16(u16& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg16( u8& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg16(u32& val) : value{ static_cast<u16>(val) }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg16(u64& val) : value{ static_cast<u16>(val) }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }

    Reg16( u32 val, u8  idx) {
        assert(idx == 0 || idx == 1);
        getWordFrom(val, idx, this->value);
        bits = value;
        this->data = value;
    }

    Reg16(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx <= 0 || idx <= 3);
        getWordFrom(val, idx, this->value);
        bits = value;
        this->data = value;
    }

    // Constructors by Register Types
    template<typename T>
    explicit Reg16(Register<T>* reg) {
        this->value = static_cast<u16>(reg->data);
        this->bits = value;
    }

};

struct Reg32 : public Register<u32> {
    u32 value;  // must be declared before std::bitset<T>
    DWord bits;

    // Default 0 Initialized Constructor
    Reg32() : value{ 0 }, bits{ value } { this->data = 0; }

    // Constructors by Register Sized Values
    explicit Reg32(u32& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg32( u8& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg32(u16& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg32(u64& val) : value{ static_cast<u32>(val) }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }   

    Reg32(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx == 0 || idx == 1);
        getDWordFrom(val, idx, this->value);
        bits = value;
        this->data = value;
    }

    // Constructors by Register Types
    template<typename T>
    explicit Reg32(Register<T>* reg) {
        this->value = static_cast<u32>(reg->data);
        this->bits = value;
    }
};

struct Reg64 : public Register<u64> {
    u64 value;  // must be declared before std::bitset<T>
    QWord bits;

    // Default 0 Initialized Constructor
    Reg64() : value{ 0 }, bits{ value } { this->data = 0; }

    // Constructors by Register Sized Values
    explicit Reg64(u64& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value }{
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg64( u8& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg64(u16& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }
    explicit Reg64(u32& val) : value{ val }, bits{ value } {
        this->data = value;
    }


    // Constructors by Register Types
    template<typename T>
    explicit Reg64(Register<T>* reg) {
        this->value = static_cast<u64>(reg->data);
        this->bits = value;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg8& r);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg16& r);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg32& r);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg64& r);
```

Now I went and turned these into template classes to reduce a lot of the code duplication. And this is what I have so far:

**Register.h** - *Newer Version*

```
template<typename Ty>
struct Register_t {
    static constexpr u16 BitCount = sizeof(Ty) * CHAR_BIT;

    Ty currentValue;
    Ty previousValue;
    std::bitset<BitCount> bits;

    Register_t() : 
        currentValue{ 0 }, 
        previousValue{ 0 }, 
        bits{ 0 }{}

    template<typename U>
    explicit Register_t(U val) : 
        currentValue{ static_cast<Ty>(val) }, 
        previousValue{ 0 }, 
        bits{ currentValue } {}

    template<typename U>
    explicit Register_t(Register_t<U>& r) {
        this->currentValue = static_cast<Ty>(r->currentValue);
        this->bits = r->bits;
    }        
};

template<typename Ty>
struct Register : public Register_t<Ty> {
    Register() = default;
    explicit Register(Ty val) : Register_t<Ty>( val ) {}    

    // Reg8
    template<typename U>
    Register( u16 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx == 0 || idx == 1);
        getByteFrom(val, idx, currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    Register(u32 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx <= 0 && idx >= 3);
        getByteFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    Register(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx <= 0 && idx <= 7);
        getByteFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    // Reg16
    Register(u32 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx == 0 || idx == 1);
        getWordFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    Register(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx <= 0 && idx <= 3);
        getWordFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    // Reg32
    Register(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx == 0 || idx == 1);
        getDWordFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }
};

using Reg8  = Register<u8>;
using Reg16 = Register<u16>;
using Reg32 = Register<u32>;
using Reg64 = Register<u64>;
```

Now when it comes to the constructors that will take a `std::uintx_t` type as well as an index value. Some of the constructor declarations match for example:

In the original version `Reg8` has `Reg8(u32 val, u8 idx)` and `Reg16` has `Reg16(u32 val, u8 idx)`. And if you look closer `Reg8(...)` asserts that `idx <= 0 && idx >= 3` while `Reg16(...)` asserts that `idx == 0 || idx == 1`.

However when I try to template these classes and port over the constructors, these now become ambiguous. I don't know how to determine which assert to use to distinguish between it being an `Reg8`, `Reg16`, `Reg32` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like everything in your class comes down to using [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) and [`numeric_limits::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) of the unsigned version of your type.

I've written up for you below a rough draft of how I think the class could look:

```
template <typename T>
struct Register {
    T data;
    T value;
    bitset<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT> bits;

    Register() : data(), value() {}

    template <typename P>
    explicit Register(const P val) : data(static_cast<T>(val)), value(data), bits(data) {}

    template <typename P>
    Register(const P val, const unsigned char idx) : data(static_cast<T>((val >> std::size(bits) * idx) & numeric_limits<make_unsigned_t<T>>::max())), value(data), bits(data) {
        assert(idx == '\0' || idx < sizeof(P) / sizeof(T));
    }

    template <typename P>
    Register(const Register<P>& reg) : data(static_cast<T>(reg.data)), value(data), bits(data) {}
};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Register<T>& r) {
  os << "Reg" << size(r.bits) << '(' << r.data << ")\nhex: 0x" << uppercase << setfill('0') << setw(sizeof(T) * 2) << hex << r.data << dec << "\nbin: ";

  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size(r.bits); ++i) {
    cout.put('0' + r.bits[i]);
  }
  return os << endl << endl;
}

template <>
ostream& operator<<<unsigned char>(ostream& os, const Register<unsigned char>& r) {
  os << "Reg" << size(r.bits) << '(' << static_cast<int>(r.data) << ")\nhex: 0x" << uppercase << setfill('0') << setw(sizeof(unsigned char) * 2) << hex << static_cast<int>(r.data) << dec << "\nbin: ";

  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < size(r.bits); ++i) {
    cout.put('0' + r.bits[i]);
  }
  return os << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Close; but the various constructors I have for the smaller types that accept a larger type and an index depends on that type. The `sizeof(p)` alone isn't quite enough:`Reg8(u16 , idx)`  `idx` range `[0-1]`; `Reg8(u32, idx)` `idx` range `[0-3]`;  `Reg8(u64, idx)` range `[0,7]`; `Reg16(u32, idx)` `idx` range `[0,1]`; `Reg16(u64, idx)` `idx` range `[0,4]`; and `Reg32(u64, idx)` `idx` range `[0,1]`.

Comment: I still given you a thumbs up though, because the information you provided is similar and it was insightful.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Thanks for the comment, I realized that my `sizeof` in the assert was checking `P` not `T`. I've swapped that to enforce your ranges correctly, I've also added a static cast to that constructor to avoid any warnings when downcasting the type. Let me know if you have anymore issues!

Comment: Think of a cpu that has 4 different sized registers an 8bit, 16bit, 32bit and a 64bit set of registers. I'm trying to emulate that. Also I'm including the functionality of the constructors that one can construct an Reg8 from a u16, u32, u64 value as well as a Reg16, Reg32 and Reg64 directly, these will always return back the lowest byte from the word, dword and qwords. The constructors with the `idx` here is an index into those types for the caller to select which byte to retrieve from word, dword or qword respectively. The same applies for the larer types, Reg16 from Reg32, Reg64, etc.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Yup, mine do that, you saw the: `(val >> std::size(bits) * idx) & numeric_limits<make_unsigned<T>>::max()` right? Anyway I also tacked on an insertion operator for funnies.

Comment: I'll have to check that out; start up a new project and test your version and see how it behaves...

Comment: I'm going to try and incorporate this into a Virtual CPU Emulator. I want this to be base part of a Library or API that can easily be used to create many different virtual machines. I'm working on an 8080 emulator and a 6502 emulator. Instead of just having raw uchar types as a single byte and having an array of them. I'll be using these versatile multipurpose register classes. Great for debugging if you can "view" the bit sequence of that particular register!

Comment: For some reason Visual Studio is complaining about `operator<<` when I build my solution. I have the declaration in my *.h file and the definition in my *.cpp file and I have all of the necessary includes... I might become from `size(bits)` but I'm not sure. I keep getting an LNK2019 unresolved external symbol build error. Everything compiles but it is failing to build...

Comment: @FrancisCugler You can't have any of this in your implementation file. These are all templates, so they're header only.

Comment: Yeah I moved the operator to my *.h file and I had to move my #includes there too. I wasn't paying attention to the fact that the operator is template as well.

Comment: I just tried compiling it myself and noticed a couple mistakes. I updated with an edit, and it's working fine for me.

Comment: There is one issue that I am seeing with your version: `Reg<u8> r8(35);` `std::cout << r8;` gives me Reg8(#) hex: 0x0# bin:00100011. The binary sequence is correct but the values are not showing because the uchar is not being promoted to an int here.

Comment: Check the values when you template the class with a `std::uint8_t` or `unsigned char`. The `operator<<` isn't printing out the correct values because the `uchar` is not being promoted to `int` type. Might have to specialize the `operator<<` just for the `unsigned char` types.

Comment: I tried to specialize the function but it was failing due to multiple definitions. So I went and just promoted the `r.data` by doing `+r.data` into the `<<` operators for the `operator<<(...)` function. This should promote a uchar to int for proper output display.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I've added a specialization, and binary output (though this may be confusing if you're not familiar with little endian). We really should probably force all `Register` types to unsigned and should overload rather than specialize the insertion operator... but we should also have more than 24 hours in a day.

Comment: I'm aware of little & big endian. This is one of the reasons I'm trying to build this class to abstract away from it. When completed these registers should be able to automatically fix their internal values from one endian to another yet maintain the same output value! This way this class can be a universal library class for writing virtual machines with great portability.

Comment: I was also thinking you may be able to [`to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) and not have to specialize the character insertion operator...

Comment: I'm having an issue with the 2nd constructor. It's giving `error C2678: binary '&': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'int'...` I'm not just passing a value into it such as 150, 922, etc. I'm passing in variables into these constructors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193362/discussion-between-francis-cugler-and-jonathan-mee).

Comment: `std::make_unsigned` in the assertion checks needs to be `std::make_unsigned_t` also the formula for creating the upper bounds is invalid. The upper bound depends on both sizes. so the Upperbound becomes: `((sizeP > sizeT) ? (idx <= ((sizeP / sizeT)-1)) : (idx <= 0)) ` and to simplify the equation I created two `constexpr u16` for `sizeT` and `sizeP` respectively. Other than that; I believe it is working properly. Everything is as expected.

Comment: I do have one quick question; for the members you have `T data` and `T value` is there any difference between the two?

Comment: @FrancisCugler I was trying to mirror what was in the original class, which contained both: `Register`'s data and `Reg*`'s `value`. I couldn't see why you'd need both, but I also don't know your use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine the type and react appropriately, then why using generic templates at all? There are two options, determine the type and branch (by using no templates at all, by specializing your templates or possibly by using SFINAE) or write *real* generic code. The former isn't very useful, because you will end up with more boiler-plate than with no templates.

The latter depends on your requirements, but it could look something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T getXFrom(T val, std::uint8_t idx) {
  return val >> (idx * CHAR_BIT);
}

template <typename T>
class Register {
 public:
  template <typename U>
  Register(U val, std::uint8_t idx) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral_v<U>);
    assert(idx >= 0 && idx < sizeof(U));
    currentValue = getXFrom(val, idx);
  }

 private:
  T currentValue;
};
```

---

As requested, here is an example on how to specialize (using a base class to reduce redundancies):

```
template <typename T>
class Register {
 protected:
  T currentValue;
};

template <typename>
class RegisterImpl;

template <>
class RegisterImpl<uint8_t> : Register<uint8_t> {
 public:
  template <typename U>
  RegisterImpl(U val, std::uint8_t idx) {
    // uint8_t asserts...
  }
};

template <>
class RegisterImpl<uint16_t> : Register<uint16_t> {
 public:
  template <typename U>
  RegisterImpl(U val, std::uint8_t idx) {
    // uint16_t asserts...
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah; I've been working on this same code base, but I've been trying many different design decisions. My first implementation is good but I was hoping to try and reduce the amount of duplicate code by the use of templates, but now I'm getting backed into a corner with them because each different type has different constructors and some of their signatures match leading to ambiguous constructors and it's leading me into an x/y problem if I can not figure out a way to know what type this class is in order to use the appropriate constructor.

Comment: I've been trying to specialize them, but struggling with that too.

Comment: do you really need to choose different constructors? from your code snippet, the only difference is checking the range of `idx` and then extracting bytes (depending on `sizeof(T)`). this can be expressed using generic code (as my example demonstrates).

Comment: I also added an example on how to specialize

Comment: I think I figured it out; A little different than your example, so not to clutter up my original question; I'll just post an answer showing what I have done on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved my problem; I am able to compile, build and run and I am getting some expected results, but I have not done enough unit testing to verify if all cases work as expected, but this is what I have came up with so far. I had split my code into two files respectively for this to work...

**Register.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>

namespace vpc {
    typedef std::int8_t  i8;
    typedef std::int16_t i16;
    typedef std::int32_t i32;
    typedef std::int64_t i64;

    typedef std::uint8_t u8;
    typedef std::uint16_t u16;
    typedef std::uint32_t u32;
    typedef std::uint64_t u64;

    const u16 BYTE = 0x08;
    const u16 WORD = 0x10;
    const u16 DWORD = 0x20;
    const u16 QWORD = 0x40;

    typedef std::bitset<BYTE>  Byte;
    typedef std::bitset<WORD>  Word;
    typedef std::bitset<DWORD> DWord;
    typedef std::bitset<QWORD> QWord;

    // Helper Functions
    template<typename T>
    void getByteFrom(T val, u8 idx, u8& res) {
        res = ((val >> (idx * 8) & 0xff));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void getWordFrom(T val, u8 idx, u16& res) {
        res = ((val >> (idx * 16) & 0xffff));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void getDWordFrom(T val, u8 idx, u32& res) {
        res = ((val >> (idx * 32) & 0xffffffff));
    }

    template<typename T>
    struct Register_t {
        static constexpr u16 BitCount = sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT;

        T currentValue;
        T previousValue;
        std::bitset<BitCount> bits;

        Register_t() :
            currentValue{ 0 }, 
            previousValue{ 0 }, 
            bits{ 0 }
        {}

        template<typename U>
        explicit Register_t(U val) : 
            currentValue{ static_cast<T>(val) }, 
            previousValue{ 0 }, 
            bits{ currentValue }
        {}

        template<typename U>
        explicit Register_t(Register_t<U>& r) : previousValue{ 0 }
        {
            this->currentValue = static_cast<T>(r.currentValue);
            this->bits = currentValue;
        }        
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Register : public Register_t<T> {
        Register() : Register_t<T>() {}
        explicit Register(T val) : Register_t<T>( val ) {}  

        template<typename U>
        explicit Register(Register_t<U>& r) : Register_t<T>( r ) {}

       // These are the constructors with matching declarations
       // that were giving me trouble with ambiguous calls
       Register(u16 val, u8 idx);
       Register(u32 val, u8 idx);
       Register(u64 val, u8 idx);
    };

    using Reg8 = Register<u8>;
    using Reg16 = Register<u16>;
    using Reg32 = Register<u32>;
    using Reg64 = Register<u64>;

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg8&  reg);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg16& reg);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg32& reg);
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg64& reg);

} // namespace vpc
```

I now have them defined in `Register.cpp` in order to prevent `LNK Error 2005 - object already defined`.

**Register.cpp**

```
#include "Register.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace vpc {
    template<>
    Register<u8>::Register(u16 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx == 0 || idx == 1);
        getByteFrom(val, idx, currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    template<>
    Register<u8>::Register(u32 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx >= 0 && idx <= 3);
        getByteFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    template<>
    Register<u8>::Register(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx >= 0 && idx <= 7);
        getByteFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    // Reg16
    template<>
    Register<u16>::Register(u32 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx == 0 || idx == 1);
        getWordFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    template<>
    Register<u16>::Register(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx >= 0 && idx <= 3);
        getWordFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    // Reg32
    template<>
    Register<u32>::Register(u64 val, u8 idx) {
        assert(idx == 0 || idx == 1);
        getDWordFrom(val, idx, this->currentValue);
        this->bits = this->currentValue;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg8& r) {
        os << "Reg8(" << +r.currentValue << ")\n"
            << "hex: " << "0x" << std::uppercase
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex
            << +r.currentValue << std::dec << '\n'
            << "bin: " << r.bits << '\n' << std::endl;
        return  os;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg16& r) {
        os << "Reg16(" << r.currentValue << ")\n"
            << "hex: " << "0x" << std::uppercase
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << std::hex
            << r.currentValue << std::dec << '\n'
            << "bin: " << r.bits << '\n' << std::endl;
        return  os;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg32& r) {
        os << "Reg32(" << r.currentValue << ")\n"
            << "hex: " << "0x" << std::uppercase
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex
            << r.currentValue << std::dec << '\n'
            << "bin: " << r.bits << '\n' << std::endl;
        return  os;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Reg64& r) {
        os << "Reg64(" << r.currentValue << ")\n"
            << "hex: " << "0x" << std::uppercase
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << std::hex
            << r.currentValue << std::dec << '\n'
            << "bin: " << r.bits << '\n' << std::endl;
        return  os;
    }

} // namespace vpc
```

Now my application program:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Register.h"

int main() {
    using namespace vpc;

    u16 val = 1420;

    Reg16 r16(val);     // used to show a 16 bit register
    Reg8  r8A(val, 0);  // construct an 8 bit register from low byte of val
    Reg8  r8B(val, 1);  // construct an 8 bit register from high byte of val    

    std::cout << r16 << r8A << r8B;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And I am getting this for output:

```
Reg16(1420)
hex: 0x058C
bin: 0000010110001100

Reg8(140)
hex: 0x8C
bin: 10001100

Reg8(5)
hex: 0x05
bin: 00000101
```